# email from ApexApplication

Tags: apex

We've been receiving emails from ApexApplication with the subject Developer script exception.  The body of the email says something like:

> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 005E0000001rJPN/00DE0000000dkKp
>
> Failed to process batch for class '' for job id '707E000000pfgGa'

How do I find out what is causing these exceptions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a Batch Apex class that is throwing errors.

In Setup -> Monitoring -> Apex Jobs, you should see a log of all your batch apex classes. Find the log for your job ID `707E000000pfgGa` and it'll display which class was invoked.

Comment: What to do if the log is not generated there and the job status is 'Completed' with 0 failures